# How can I add codes like this on MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

How can I add codes like this on MediaWiki below the article page?

```
<div id="related-list2" class="related-articles-list2">
<h2 class="top-title">Related Posts  :  <?php the_title();?></h2>
<br>
<ul id="categories-list" class="row categories-list">
<?php 
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=> 18,
);
$related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); 
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your LocalSettings.php you could add something like this

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function( $out, $skin ) {
   $out->addHTML( \Html::element( 'p', [], 'YOUR OUTPUT WILL BE HERE' ) );
};
```

$out is an OutputPage object see here for more information https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:OutputPage.php